# Monthly percentage of year [PowerBi] [Dax]

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm quite new to Power Bi and DAX in general and I have some problems calculating how much of each month was of the whole year.

```
Example: 

Year 2021: 
Month  Value  Percentage
Jan.    100       10   
Feb.     50        5 
Mar.    250       25
Apr.     30        3
Etc...
Total  1000       100
```

I have calculated the percentage column in dax as:

```
   = 
   [Value] /
    CALCULATE(
        [Value],
        ALLEXCEPT(Calendar, Calendar[Year])
        
    )
```

This gives me the correct result for the chosen year, the problem I have is when trying to compare it to last year's result.

I've tried to add
"SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(Calendar[Key_Calendar])" and "PARALLELLPERIOD(CALENDAR[Key_Calendar],-12,Month)"

but neither of them gives me the result I am looking for.

I'd appreciate any help that I can get on the issue.

Comment: Your Percentage column calculation is incorrect! You need an aggregate function (SUM). Please try this: Percentage = 
   [Value] /
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Calendar'[Value]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Calendar', 'Calendar'[Year])  
    ). In addition to this, If you want to use time intelligence functions, you need a date table besides fact table! To summarize, data structure should be designed from scratch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create such a model:

[image: Model]

If you want to create a simple calendar table, create new table and paste this code:

```
Calendar = 
VAR BaseTable = CALENDAR(DATE(2020,01,01), DATE(2021,12,31))
RETURN
ADDCOLUMNS(
    BaseTable,
    "Year", YEAR([Date]),
    "Month", MONTH([Date]),
    "MonthName", FORMAT([Date],"mmm"),
    "Quarter", QUARTER([Date]),
    "Period", FORMAT([Date],"yyyy-mm")
    )
```

Your resulting Date table:

[image: Date Table]

Then create a fact table with some data:

```
Date    Value
01/01/2021  100
01/02/2021  50
01/03/2021  250
01/04/2021  30
01/05/2021  25
01/06/2021  50
01/07/2021  65
01/08/2021  75
01/09/2021  70
01/10/2021  35
01/11/2021  40
01/12/2021  20
01/01/2020  10
01/02/2020  25
01/03/2020  65
01/04/2020  85
01/05/2020  35
01/06/2020  25
01/07/2020  35
01/08/2020  10
01/09/2020  30
01/10/2020  50
01/11/2020  30
01/12/2020  20
```

Then we can create 2 new measures!

```
Percentage = 
DIVIDE(SUM(FactTable[Value]),CALCULATE(SUM(FactTable[Value]),ALL(FactTable)))


Percentage_LastYear = 
CALCULATE(
    [Percentage],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date])
)
```

Then create a table visual and put it like you see in the below screenshot:

[image: Result]

And you are Good to go! I hope It solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Calendar` dimension has a date column called `Date`, the following would get the value for the prior year:

```
Value PY =
CALCULATE ( [Value], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( 'Calendar'[Date] ) )
```